# try_files in a regex specific location in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm fairly new to regex and nginx and I want to accomplish this:

domain.com/username    {no trailing slash    } to point to domain.com/profile/user/username
domain.com/username/   {with trailing slash  } to point to domain.com/profile/user/username

```
location ~ ^/(?<username>[A-Za-z0-9\.\_]+)/?$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /profile/user/$username/?rewrite=1&$args;
}
```

works fine just a couple of issues.
1. The location / is trying files too, I don't want that.
2. If I delete the ? at the end of the regex string to make the / strict, the first problem is resolved but then the username without the trailing slash will not be tried.

Comment: I cannot see how `/` matches the above regex, with or without the penultimate `?`. Are you sure it is not a side effect from somewhere else in your configuration?

Comment: I can post the nginx server config file if it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding a trailing slash to all URLs as below:

```
location / {
     root            /usr/share/nginx/html/domain.com;
     index           index.php index.htm index.html;
     rewrite         ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
}
location ~ ^/(?<user>[A-Za-z0-9\.\_]+)/$ {
     try_files       $uri $uri/ /$uri/ /profile/user/$user/;
}
```